# How can I get a price of any item in a textbox when I write its name in a combobox beside it

Tags: list, combobox, addition, info

I have a sales user form and it is divided to comboboxes and textboxes … and also I have an excel sheet contains all the details of the items like a warehouse inventory…
How can I get a price of any item in the textbox when I write its name in a combobox beside it automatically in VBA though I have a big list of items and their prices …?

Thank you for feedback
Mohamed Adnan
Iraq
mohamed.iraqi77@gmail.com

I asked a question and expect a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.